# Issue with preselected state on app load

Tags: ios, swift3, collectionview, nsindexpath

I am trying to have a preselected state upon app load but am receiving an error with this code. Not sure what is wrong...thanks in advance.

```
let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving ? If you are using swift 3, I recommend using `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)` whereas `NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your pre-selecting cell code inside Main Dispatch with as per your requirements: -

## Swift 3.0

#### Select Cell Horizontally

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionDate.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

#### Select Cell Vertically

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionDate.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
}
```